# Select top node with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Here's an exapmle of xml I'm dealing with:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <table id="table1">
            <div>
                <table id="table2"/>
            </div>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create an XPath expression, which would select table1 and would not select table2. The ids are there for example and are not present in the original document. The structure of those documents may be much more convoluted as well. I want to select the top table for processing.

Is it possible to do this with XPath alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work even for multiple "top-level" tables:

```
//table[not(ancestor::table)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that:

Some examples:

```
/div/div/table

//table[.//table]

(//table)[1]
```

I do not know how your xml looks like, but all the examples above will only return the first table.

```
//table[1]  - this one will return both tables.
```